# curl url with post data, username and password and response as file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, curl

I am using to call a url from command prompt of curl. The url contains post data, user name and password. Added to that the response should be a file if authenticates or shows generally 401 response. I have been trying to find out the solution for the last 2 hours, but cant able to do that. For example i want to send two values(x,y) using post and with that i am sending the username and password also, say for instance

```
curl -u test@test.com:test http://www.example.com/mappingFile
```

if i sending like this i am getting

```
<html><head><title>Error 405 Request method 'GET' not supported</title></head>
<body><h2>Error 405 Request method 'GET' not supported</h2></body>
</html>
```

Please any body can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -d "appid=1234567" --header "username:test@test.com" --header "password:test" >> output.apk http://example.com/fileName.apk
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not posting any data with the curl command and hence it is going as a `GET` instead of `POST`.
Here is how you can send the `POST` request using `--data` option:

```
curl --data "dummyparam=dummvalue" -u test@test.com:test http://www.example.com/mappingFile
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr. Juned. I already accepted the previous answer even though your answer is perfect because it comes first. sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you send the data via `GET`.
use `curl --request POST` to send data via `POST`.
The data you can add with the option `--data`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr. User. If i use like that i am getting 400 bad request exception